# iOS sdk - setup passcode in my app

Tags: ios, security

I am wanting to set up the option for a user to set up a passcode upon launching the app.

Now I am looking for a tutorial, or documentation everywhere, but unless I am looking for the wrong terminology, i cannot find what I am looking for.

When you launch apps that have this option it says the word "passcode" but type that into apple documentation and nothing comes up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because this has to be implemented by yourself. There is no standard way in the SDK. Take a look on how to access the Keychain on iOS (Tutorial: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/3/29/simple-iphone-keychain-access.html) to store and check passwords. You could then check upon launch of your app if a password is set and if that's the case, present your login view, if not present the "set password view"

Comment: I'll get back to you, at this stage the app is still on the drawing board, so I was just planning to see what is available and what I need to write myself. Looks like this may come into a 2.0 update:-)